# My mathematical friend

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

I have a friend who is a mathematician but a puzzler at the same time.

Whenever I call him and ask him what he is doing, he gives an awkward answer,

Like when he was working on vectors , he told me "I am figuring out directions to my way home."

when he was working on 3-D,he said "I am sorting my workspace."

Yesterday when I called him, he said "I am fixing ceiling and roof of my house."

What is he working on?

Comment: _Why_ __mathematics__ tag was not applied to this?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay because I forgot to :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is :

> Number Theory

Because

> We have [**Roof** function(**Ceiling** or least integer function)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CeilingFunction.html)
> ([floor and ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) are introduced in number theory).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he is:

> fixing his ceiling and roof of his house?

Because of what he said on the phone